# Computing a few difficult metrics from an integer vector in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

For some context, I am working with sports / basketball data. The following vector is for 1 NBA game, and contains the number of points that the home team was ahead or behind at any given point in the game.

```
dput(leads_vector)
c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, 
-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 
5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 
11, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 15, 
14, 14, 13, 13, 13, 13, 11, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 16, 
16, 13, 13, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 9, 9, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 15, 13, 13, 13, 13, 15, 12, 12, 12, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 10, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 11, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 10, 12, 10, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 14, 14, 14, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 15, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 14, 14, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 8, 11, 8, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 9, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 18, 18, 18, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 18, 18, 18, 16, 16, 16, 13, 13, 13, 11, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13)
```

These vectors always start with 0, since the game begins tied at 0-0. leads_vector[100] equals 14, which means the home team was winning by 14 at this point in the game. Note that the numbers in the vector repeat, since the score can remain the same for several plays in a row in a basketball game.

The 4 metrics I would like to compute are:

- Biggest Lead
- Number of times the game was tied
- Longest run (consecutive points for one team)
- Lead changes

Biggest Lead is easy to compute:

```
biggest_lead <- abs(max(leads_vector))
```

Number of times the game was tied is a bit more difficult to compute:

```
times_tied <- sum(leads_vector[2:length(leads_vector)] == 0 & leads_vector[1:(length(leads_vector)-1)] != 0)
```

times_tied checks for all instances in the vector where the value is 0 (the score is tied), and the preceding value in the vector is not 0. This ensures that each sequence of zeros counts as the score being tied only once.

I am not sure how to compute longest run. The longest run in the game is the largest monotonically increasing or decreasing sequence in the vector. Just using the eye test, I notice a long run of 8 at leads_vector[38:65].

Number of lead changes is difficult to compute as well. It would be equal to the number of times the lead went from positive to negative in this vector. The following leads_vector:

```
c(3, -3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 2, -3, -1, -4, -5, -2, 0, 1)
```

... would have 4 lead changes (from 3 to -3, from -3 to 2, from 2 to -3, and from -2 to 0 to 1).

Any help with this is appreciated!

EDIT - longest run is the tough stat to compute here, but i'm working on it.
EDIT2 - i think longest run will be easier to compute if i remove repeat values from leads_vector. but i cannot use duplicated() function, because that will remove duplicates in different places in the vector. Instead i'd want to only remove repeat values next to each other (get c(0, -2, 5, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11, 9, 11, 9, 11, ... ))

Comment: For `longest_run` do you need actual sequence or its length?

Comment: I'd like the value of the longest run, not the length of the sequence. In the example I mentioned, the value would be 8 since the home lead increased from 3 to 11 without a decrease at any point in the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing of longest run:

```
compute_longest_run <- function(x) {
  # Collapse repetitions
  x_unique <- rle(x)$values

  # Compute score change
  score_change <- diff(x_unique)

  # Need to compute sum of all subvectors with the same sign
  run_side <- sign(score_change)
  run_id <- c(1, cumsum(diff(run_side) != 0) + 1)
  run_value <- tapply(score_change, run_id, sum)

  max(abs(run_value))
}

compute_longest_run(leads_vector)
#> [1] 10
```

Comment: this is great, i am fairly certain this is calculating the correct value, checking everything now

Comment: great use of tapply()

Answer (score 2):

```
#biggest_lead
with(rle(leads_vector), max(abs(values)))

#number_ties
with(rle(leads_vector), sum(values == 0))

#longest_run

#lead_changes 
length(rle(leads_vector[leads_vector != 0] < 0)$values)
```

Comment: this is great, did not know about rle

Comment: I'm a bit confused regarding the use of with() here, does it simply pass the data parameter data = rle(leads_vector) as a parameter to the rest of the with() call?

Comment: it looks like the rle()$value accounts for the number_ties, the sequential plays with the lead as 0 only show as one play with the lead as 0

Comment: however I do not want to count the initial score 0 - 0 as a tie, so I think i just need sum(values == ) - 1

Comment: Also `longest_run` equals to 8 by coincidence. `8` is the value of the most successively repeated value in `leads_vector` and not what the author is for.

Comment: @echasnovski is correct. sorry for the not 100% clear explanation. longest run is the largest change in value for any monotonically increasing / decreasing sequence in th evector.

Comment: @RobJensen that's not correct. check the example i shared with leads_vector[38:65] - this is a run of 8 since the lead went from 3 to 11 without decreasing at any point.

Comment: i think the longest run is 10, when it goes from 20 --> 10 near the end of the vector

Comment: leads_vector[483:500]

Comment: im looking at a different run

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to compute lead changes using the sign() and diff() function. First I need to filter out the values where the lead equals 0, since these are not lead changes for my calculations, even though R's sign() function has different values for (+), (-) and 0. I have this:

```
lead_changes <- sum(diff(sign(leads_vector[leads_vector != 0]))) / 2
```

For longest run, I think starting with this, to remove repeat values, is a good start:

```
lead_changes[c(TRUE, lead_changes[-1] != hL[-length(hLlead_changes])]
```